# Need ID of my errors/omissions in PowerShell script reading CSV and outputing TXT file

Tags: powershell, csv, txt

Trying to improve a script to gen cue files, I've come up with an improvement that I hoped would be close to ideal PowerShell scripting. Sadly, it outputs a header but the subsequent (expected lines are not written to file, they are displayed on the console.

I think I am munging external variables and failing to pass them to a here-string, but I am confounded. Here is my entire script:

```
Clear-Host
Set-Location "D:\PShell"

$InFile = 'cues.csv'
$OutFile = 'Cues.cue'
$Maker = 'Yours Truly'
$Product = 'Awful Good'


$DocHead1 = 'REM MP3 CueFileRmrks'
$DocHead2 = 'FILE "' + $Product + '.mp3" MP3'

$TrakTitlPrfx = ' TITLE '
$TrakIndxPrfx = ' INDEX 01 '
$TrakRemsPrfx = ' REM GW '


$Parts = @()
    Import-CSV -Delimiter "`t" $InFile

    Set-Content "$OutFile" -Value 'REM GoldWave'
    Add-Content "$OutFile" -Value $TitleHdr

    foreach($item in $Parts)
        {
        "$Nmbr = $($item.Nbr) and $Titl = $($item.Title) and $Time = $($item.Time) and $Dscr = $($item.Description)"

        $Time = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,2).text      # Cue's time location
        $Title = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,3).text     # Cue's name
        $Rmrks = $sheet.Cells.Item($i,4).text    # Text associated with cue

        $TitleLine = $TrakTitlPrfx + "{0:d3}" -f + $i + " " + $Title
        $IndexLine = $TrakIndxPrfx + $Time
        $DescrLine = $TrakRemsPrfx + $Rmrks

        Add-Content "$OutFile" "  TRACK $Nmbr AUDIO"
        Add-Content "$OutFile" "    $TitleLine"
        Add-Content "$OutFile" "    $IndexLine"
        if ($null, $Rmrks -ne $null)
            {
            Add-Content "$OutFile" "    $DescrLine"
            }

        }
```

ANY comments will be appreciated.

Comment: `Import-CSV -Delimiter "`t" $InFile` is neither captured in a variable nor sent through the pipeline, so its output will go to the console (host).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to store your input file into a variable, i.e. change this:

```
$Parts = @()
    Import-CSV -Delimiter "`t" $InFile
```

To this:

```
$Parts = Import-CSV -Delimiter "`t" $InFile
```

Where you take the output from `Import-CSV` and store it in a variable that you then iterate through (e.g. the for loop).

Second, this:

```
"$Nmbr = $($item.Nbr) and $Titl = $($item.Title) and $Time = $($item.Time) and $Dscr = $($item.Description)"
```

Will simply output to the console. You actually want it to go somewhere, so you need to `Add-Content` like this:

```
Add-Content "$OutFile" -Value "$Nmbr = $($item.Nbr) and $Titl = $($item.Title) and $Time = $($item.Time) and $Dscr = $($item.Description)"
```

Comment: thank you, thank you, thank you! Both corrections make a lot of sense but honestly, I just could not clear up my thinking.